# Bootstrap scrollspy not doing anything

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have looked at other similar questions and can't seem to find a solution.

I have the .nav class on my menu, the data-target is, I believe, pointing at the right element.

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#main-nav" data-offset="300">
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#main-container").css("display", "none");
        $("#main-container").fadeIn(2000);
        $("a.transition").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        linkLocation = this.href;
        $("#main-container").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage);
    });
        function redirectPage() {
        window.location = linkLocation;
    }
  });
</script>
<div id="main-header">
  <h1>Springfield, NY</h1>
</div><!--Navbar-->
<nav id="main-nav" class="navbar navbar-inverse container nav">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display-->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling-->
    <div id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Classes<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="classes.html#sectYouth">Youth Class (5-10)</a></li>
            <li><a href="classes.html#sectKids">Older Kids Class (10+)</a></li>
            <li><a href="classes.html#sectAdults">Teens/Adults Class </a></li>
            <li><a href="classes.html#sectAiki">Aiki Jiu-Jitsu</a></li>
            <li><a href="classes.html#sectPrivate">Private Classes</a></li>
            <li><a href="classes.html#sectCorporate">Corporate Seminars</a></li>
            <li><a href="classes.html#sectDefense">Self Defense</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="instructors.html">Instructors</a></li>
        <li><a href="sister.html">Sister Dojos</a></li>
        <li><a href="testimonial.html">Testimonials</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallerys.html">Gallerys</a></li>
        <li><a href="calendar.html">Calendar</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Information<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="articles.html">Articles</a></li>
            <li><a href="studentinfo.html">Student Info</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.nav-collapse-->
  </div>
  <!-- END Navbar-->
</nav><!--End of Navbar-->
```

I would be most happy for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

On the page classes.html which I assume is the page you want to change the active class in your navbar the links in your navbar should not have the page preceeding the hash location in your links.  So on the page classes.html if you have the links in your navbar written like so  `<a href="classes.html#sectYouth"></a>` the scrollspy plugin will not recognize them and therefore will not change the active class when scrolling to the # location.  So just on the page classes.html remove the page name and just use the # location like so `<a href="#sectYouth"></a>`  and on all other pages you can keep it the same as you have it with the page name before the # location so it will point to the proper page.  Also I know you stated that you have the .nav class in your `<nav>` tag.  This is not neccesary for the plugin to function and is normally used for the inner nav sections.  So you may want to consider removing this from your `<nav>` tag and just use .navbar and .navbar-inverse along with your container class.  It is probably not hurting anything there but it is normally used for the inner `<ul class="nav navbar-nav">` and not the outer navbar itself.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I will give it a try later. I'm redoing those pages anyway so that each class has its own page anyway so maybe that will clear up the issue too.

Comment: If you are going to have each section to have its own page then there is no need to use scrollspy.  Scrollspy is used for single page navigation.  It changes the active class of your nav links and scrolls to sections of the page.  If you just have different pages for everything in your navigation then you just add the class of active to the li like you have in your example for the link to your homepage <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>  So on each page add that class of active if the page matches the link.

Comment: Ok perhaps I was looking at this wrong. I was looking to make my navbar sit below the header till it's scrolled down. In which case, the header scrolls up but the navbar then stays at the top.

Comment: Oh ya scrollspy will not do this.  Like I said it is for single page navigation so when you have different sections on a one page layout it will scroll to the section when clicking on the links and change the active class of the link.  Here is an example of scrollspy. https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/w36wzubr/ you may need to resize the window bigger to see the effects.  What you are looking for can be done wth jquery.  Here is an example of that https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/esem4mc6/  Read the comments I have made in the javascript section.